# multiple loops in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am new to flow and here is my use case :

When an account is update -> I have to look for all related opp and then --> for all the opp record I have to look for all related Assignment custom object and change the assignment name of all record that are related to the opp (who are also related to the account starting the flow )

I did a first Loop  to get all the related opp but when i tried to use this record in the second loop it doesn't work and i am lost with the criteria condition.
How can I solve this ?
Thanks guys,

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by it doesnt work? do you want to share what your second loop looks like as it is cropped here. You can just use 'AssignEachOppInCollection' loop variable (if it is not a loop, you need to create one) and loop through it, create a new update collection and update it if needed.